# $G_1$ of a nodal projective curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

Let $C$ be the projective nodal curve over the field $k$ i.e. the projective line with two points identified. I'm having trouble calculating the $G$-theory of $C$, especially $G_1$. Writing the localization sequence wrt closed subscheme the singular point we get: $$G_1(k)\rightarrow G_1(C) \rightarrow G_1(k[t,t^{-1}])\rightarrow G_0(k)\rightarrow G_0(
C)\rightarrow G_0(k[t,t^{-1}])\rightarrow 0$$
This reduces to: $$k^{\times}\rightarrow G_1(C) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus k^{\times}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G_0(C)\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$$
The question is whether $G_0(k)\rightarrow G_0(C)$ is injective or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The morphism $G_0(C) \to G_0(k)$ induced by the pushforward via the structure morphism $C \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$ splits the morphism $G_0(k) \to G_0(C)$, hence the latter is injective.

Comment: Isn't the pushforward same as taking global sections? This is left exact unless the coherent sheaves are globally generated, how does that define a homomorphism?

Comment: @user127776 $G$ theory is covariant with respect to proper morphism. You are right that $f_*:Sh(X)\to Sh(Y)$ is only left exact, but if $f$ is proper and $\mathcal{F}$ is coherent then $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ is also coherent and you define the pushforward in $G$ theory as $f_*[\mathcal{F}]=\sum (-1)^i[R^if_*\mathcal{F}]$.